# uiwebview warning ,objective c

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting this warning: `local declaration of webView hides instance variable`

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: You probably have an ivar named webView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class you already have a variable called webView. You can change its name or change your method signature with something like this :

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

This should be good :)

Comment: thanks i was able to strip the warning.....but was not able to execute the javascript which returns the html content from the webpage....cud u help me

Comment: What is the problem ? NSString *js_result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"]; The var js_result is null ?

Comment: de thing is i want to embed the result (*js_result) in webview.....de thing is i want to pull the html content rather than showing the entire website in uiwebview